# How to reset an extension setting on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I had installed the Gitlab Workflow extension in VS Code. I need to change the OAuth token and already configured username and password for that extension. How do I do that?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exposes the command `GitLab: Remove Account from VS Code` to the command palette - that should do the job.